# How to apply css on a div which is in some container but shown with respect to screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created my custom modal with position: fixed and use this modal into content but it's not applied with respect to screen its shows position: fixed with respect to content How can I make modal in the center with respect to screen center?

modal is imported into the content.

where nav position is fixed
sidebar position is fixed
content position is relative
and modal position is already fixed but this fixed position of modal take w.r.t its parent not with body

Problem: Modal takes the fixed position with respect to its parent but I need to apply modal with respect to HTML body tag. Is there any way to apply this?

Can't put modal directly to body because it's created in such a way that where it'll put, it'll automatically used to draw w.r.to body

Also use parent selector

```
.overlay{
 animation: ${fadeIn} 200ms ease-out;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 999;
 background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.palette.greyScale[9]};
 }
body < parent(body) {
 position:relative;
}
```

does not work.

Here is the structure:

[image]

Comment: Move the modal out of the content. Put it directly in `<body>`. (This still sounds fishy to me, `fixed` should ignore parent elements; can you show a [mre]?)

Comment: I agree with @ChrisG, `position: fixed` is relative to the [browser window](https://zellwk.com/blog/css-positions/#fixed).

Comment: Ok, my first guess in that case is that you're calculating the coordinates wrong maybe? How do you come up with the modal's `left` and `top` properties?

Comment: nope this is coordinates of overlay outside of modal the grey screen.modal is centerized to overlay overlay needs to select parent of body not that container

Comment: A modal of position:fixed is not going to care about an overlay element that is positioned absolutely. Please create a [mre] so we can debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the layout is not correct. I suggest the following layout and style.
Put everything inside a container. I have created a jsfiddle with sample layout. Please have a look. Let me know if any queries
[image]

```css
.container {
    background: lightgray;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.nav-bar {
  widows: 100%;
  height:20%;
  background: gray;
}
.side-bar {
  width:20%;
  height: calc(100% - 20%);
  float: left;
  background: lightblue;
}
.content {
  width: calc(100% - 20%);
  background: red;
  float: left;
  height: calc(100% - 20%);
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav-bar">
    NavBar
  </div>
  <div class="side-bar">Side Bar</div>
  <div class="content">
  Content
    <div class="modal">
      Modal
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```